# Generate XML using namespace prefix in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

what is the modification i need to provide for the code to bring out below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <CheckInLoad xmlns="http://fake.com/schemas/insert"         xmlns:cmn="http://fake.com/schemas/common" >
<Input>
  <cmn:EmpId>100</cmn:EmpId>
</Input>
</CheckInLoad>
```

Here is the class dfinition

```
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://fake.com/schemas/Insert")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://fake.com/schemas/Insert", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class CheckInLoad
    {
        private CheckInLoadHeader headerField;
        public CheckInLoadHeader Header
        {
            get
            {
                return this.headerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.headerField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://fake.com/schemas/Insert")]
    public partial class CheckInLoadHeader
    {

        private string empIdField;


        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://fake.com/schemas/common")]
        public string EmpId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.empIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.empIdField = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

Please let me know what kind of change needs to be done at class level. please not that, i am using below code to convert object to xml

```
     var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(load.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, load);
        return stringwriter.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("cmn", "http://fake.com/schemas/common");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(load.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, load, ns);
```

Try this.